# Can't create a table using JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

The example of code:

```
function MakeTable(Matrix){
    var newElem = document.createElement('table');
    newElem.border = "1px";
    for(var j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {
        var newRow = newElem.insertRow(j);
        for(var n = 0; n < Matrix[j].length; n++) {
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(n);
            newCell.innerText = Matrix[j][n];
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(newElem);
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear that your `table1` element isn't found in the DOM.

Comment: <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Дана матриця:</h1>
        <p>
            1-A&nbsp;&nbsp;-1&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;-1
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-1&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;-1
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-1&nbsp;&nbsp;0 &nbsp;&nbsp;0
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0&nbsp;&nbsp; 0&nbsp;&nbsp;1
        </p>

        Де А = 10^K, K = 12;
    </div>
    <div id="table1">

    </div>
</body>

Comment: If the script is in the `<head>` and it isn't using a delay to make sure it doesn't run when until the DOM is loaded, then it'll run before the element exists. Move your script to just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: What is the param `Matrix` you are passing through to `MakeTable()`? An object, array etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have an element with the `table1` ID in the DOM and as long as the script doesn't run before that element is loaded, it will work.

```js
function MakeTable(Matrix){
    var newElem = document.createElement('table');
    newElem.border = "1px";
    for(var j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {
        var newRow = newElem.insertRow(j);
        for(var n = 0; n < Matrix[j].length; n++) {
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(n);
            newCell.textContent = Matrix[j][n];
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(newElem);
}

MakeTable([["this", "is"], ["my", "table"]]);
```

```html
<div id=table1></div>
```

I also changed `.innerText` to `.textContent` since that's the standards compliant way to set text.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an element, you have to append it. Here:

```
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

Change the last line:

```
function MakeTable(Matrix){
    var newElem = document.createElement('table');
    newElem.border = "1px";
    for(var j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {
        var newRow = newElem.insertRow(j);
        for(var n = 0; n < Matrix[j].length; n++) {
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(n);
            newCell.innerText = Matrix[j][n];
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(newElem);
}
```

By convention you write the first letter of a function name in lower case (except class name).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fngqmrzp/)

Answer (score 0):

It returned out that I linked script not in the body, but in the head)